# JQuery explode prompt result not working when loading a URL

Tags: jquery, url

I am trying to create a script that asks for a YouTube video link and following explodes it and automatically inserts it into the editor.

The trick is however not working.

```
function TinyMCEInsertYouTube() {
    var YouTubeLink     = encodeURIComponent(prompt("Please insert the YouTube link"));
    var result          = $(YouTubeLink).text().split('watch?v=');
    var VideoIDParam    = result[1];

    var VideoHeight     = prompt("Please enter the video height");
    var VideoWidth      = prompt("Please enter the video width");

    var InsertCode = '<iframe width="' + VideoWidth + '" height="' + VideoHeight + '" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + VideoIDParam + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

    tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent( InsertCode );
}
```

It generates the following error :

*Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:    https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DrPpO65UbM6Y*

I already tried to add the following tags : 
**encodeURIComponent()**

But to no result

I tried to add **escape()** instead of *encodeURIComponent*
Also no result.

Gave the following error :

*Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DrPpO65UbM6Y*

**Edit!**

> It works!! Thanks to **@SearchAndResQ**
>
> The following code :
>
> ```
> function TinyMCEInsertYouTube() {
>     var YouTubeLink     = prompt("Please insert the YouTube link");
>     var result          = YouTubeLink.split('watch?v=');
>     var VideoIDParam    = result[1];
>
>     var VideoHeight     = prompt("Please enter the video height");
>     var VideoWidth      = prompt("Please enter the video width");
>
>     var InsertCode = '<iframe width="' + VideoWidth + '" height="' + VideoHeight + '" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + VideoIDParam + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
>
>     tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent( InsertCode );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YouTubeLink` is a variable containing the inputted text. you can split it directly:

`var result          = YouTubeLink.split('watch?v=');`

And you don't need to `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Another problem is that the link is URI Encoded. As such, the `split()` will not actually split anything as the `?` is encoded as `%3F`.

Comment: But `escape()` does exactly the same thing to `?`

Comment: You are right again (I am not that good in javascript, obviously). Wonder how it works for him, maybe he is not using escape anymore. You can down vote this if you feel it is not helping anyone.

Comment: The link is saved in the variable YouTubeLink from the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly split the Youtube link because `YoutubeLink` is the variable containing the inputted text.

Also there is no need for `encodeURIComponent`

Check this example i've done for you:

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3c8pz0g/1/)